Output error from the GraphCypherQAChain class of the langchain

The above code returns the context from the Neo4j graph, but the LLM is not taking the context and is returning I cannot find that information in the context. Please tell me why it is happening.
I tried to print the intermediate steps but nothing happens.

Please do not insert images of code and output. Always provide the actual text, which is much easier for us to use. In fact, your image cuts off the Full Context and Intermediate steps values, so we have no idea what the complete values are.

please print the entire result so that we can confirm if the value result['result'] really exists. Thanks.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
